# Fade text background on one end in Sony Vegas Pro 13

Tags: video, youtube, effects, vegas-pro

In Sony Vegas Pro 13, I've masked the part where I want the text's black background to appear. It looks like this:

[image]

Now, I want to fade one part of the background like in below picture, where right side of the text background is faded.

[image]

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is **luma keying**.

With luma keying, you provide a greyscale image to represent degrees of transparency (properly called an alpha channel) in addition to your background and foreground images. I have not used it in Vegas Pro, but here is a link to a tutorial: